# Data Manipulation in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have a dataset that has a primary Id (p_id) and a secondary Id (s_id). But the secondary Id is not created until the user provides some details that are requested. Till the user does not provide that details, secondary Id remains NA. I want a way that I can replace all the NA's with the Secondary Id.

```
p_id | s_id   | Amount | P_date
123  | NA     | 20     | 10/02/2017
123  | NA     | 15     | 10/02/2017
123  | abc123 | 15     | 10/03/2017
123  | abc123 | 22     | 10/05/2017
456  | NA     | 26     | 10/02/2017
456  | NA     | 30     | 10/04/2017
456  | NA     | 10     | 10/05/2017
456  | aws456 | 05     | 10/06/2017
456  | aws456 | 05     | 10/06/2017
678  | NA     | 10     | 10/03/2017
678  | rty678 | 10     | 10/04/2017
```

Once we know that what is the secondary Id for that particular user, we need to replace all the NA with the actual secondary Id

```
p_id | s_id   | Amount | P_date
123  | abc123 | 20     | 10/02/2017
123  | abc123 | 15     | 10/02/2017
123  | abc123 | 15     | 10/03/2017
123  | abc123 | 22     | 10/05/2017
456  | aws456 | 26     | 10/02/2017
456  | aws456 | 30     | 10/04/2017
456  | aws456 | 10     | 10/05/2017
456  | aws456 | 05     | 10/06/2017
456  | aws456 | 05     | 10/06/2017
678  | rty678 | 10     | 10/03/2017
678  | rty678 | 10     | 10/04/2017
```

I need to use select query to have this data in PostgreSQL.

Comment: Does this table have a primary key ? If not: Why not?

Answer (score 0):

This violates the [third normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form), and the problem you are experiencing is connected to that.

You should remove `s_id` from the table and have a second table with only `p_id` and `s_id`, where `p_id` is the primary key. Then introduce a foreign key constraint from your original table to this second table.

That way there is no need to update all entries with the same `p_id` once `s_id` changes – the problem just goes away.